# Loop through all the images inside directory and convert to base64

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, base64

I am trying to loop through all the images in my folder convert it into base64 and send to MongoDB.

I started with one image, worked fine.

```
var filename = '1500.jpg';
var binarydata = fs.readFileSync(filename); 
var converted = new Buffer(binarydata).toString("base64");
console.log(converted);
```

The above code gives me base64 for one file.

I tried changing the code so that it will loop through all the files in my directory and give me base64 for each file.
here is what I wrote but it did not work;

```
var variantfolder = './variantimages';
fs.readdir(variantfolder, function(err, files){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {
    fs.readFileSync(files, function(err, res){
      if (err){console.log('err')} else {
        var converted = new Buffer(res).toString("base64");
        var onevariant = {
          "imagename":files,
          "imagebase64":converted
        }
        var newvariant = new Variant(onevariant)
        newvariant.save(err, newvar){
          if (err) {
            console.log('err');
          }
          else {
            console.log('saved to mongo');
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: ```files``` is an array, thus you should loop over the array by using ```files.forEach(function (file){....})```

Comment: Why would you do this!!??  MongoDB supports binary.... this is crazy.

Comment: @brad I don't get you. There is a system that is going to consume images that are coming in through an API as base64. There are about fixed one time 1000 images, which I am planning to convert from my local host into base64 and just give an api that calls the records of MongoDb document and they can consume it.

Comment: Base64 encoding adds 33% overhead to the storage, and requires additional memory and CPU.  It's almost never actually necessary.  I don't know why you would have an API that sends images as base64... there are so many other ways to send the binary data with such an API.  You definitely shouldn't store it that way in your database.  A total waste of resources.

Comment: @mysamza when you say "but it did not work", what do you mean exactly? What happened, what errors did you see, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem will be related to you calling functions in the wrong ways.
Check the inputs and outputs of the functions you are using.

The [fs.readdir()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) function callback is passed 2 parameters, an error and an array of file names.

The [fs.readFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) function takes the parameters path and options. It also returns the file contents, it doesn't take a callback. The callback version is [fs.readFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback).

So in your code you are passing an array of file names into the file path parameter, which will not work.

You can also pass base64 as the encoding when reading the file and you won't have to convert it after.

I expect you will want something more along these lines (add your own error handling as required):

```
fs.readdir(variantfolder, (err, fileNames) => {
  fileNames.forEach((fileName) => {
    fs.readFile(`${variantfolder}/${fileName}`, 'base64', (err, base64Data) => {
      // Do your thing with the file data.
    });
  });
});
```

Note that you can use the async, sync or promise (fs.promises) version of the fs functions depending on what is most suitable for your code.